# How to align the legend in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The mwe is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \addlegendentry{Short Legend}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
    \addlegendentry{Very very long Legend}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two legends have the different length and they vertical align at the center. Now I want to align the legend at the left. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need add to axis option :`legend cell align=left` (see Manual for Package PGFPLOTS, page255):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend cell align=left]% <--- added 
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
    \addlegendentry{Short Legend}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
    \addlegendentry{Very very long Legend}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. I didn't read the manual carefully. Now I believe the manual is the best reference.